# Set theory question regarding $A\overline{\sim} B = \{x+y : <x,y>\in A\times B\}$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

Given $A,B \in P(N)$ We mark $\overline{\sim}$ as
$$A\overline{\sim} B = \{x+y : \langle x,y\rangle\in A\times B\}$$
Now, order R will be as following
$ARB$ iff $\exists M\in P(N)$ so $A\overline{\sim} M=B$.

The question is 
R is reflexive? symmetric? anti-symmetric? transitive?
I think R is partial order, i.e reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.
and I need to prove it.
I think my proof is correct for reflexive so let`s focus on anti-symmetric and transitive.

Just for make it sure - N is Set of Natural numbers, including zero.

Here what I done for proving transitive:

Let $A,B,C \in P(N)$ and assume ARB and BRC.

ARB so exists $T \in P(N)$ so $A\overline{\sim} T=B$

BRC so exists $S \in P(N)$ so $B\overline{\sim} S=C$

Let define M as following set: $\{K+P | k\in T$ and $p\in S\}$

$S,T\in P(N)$ so $M\in P(N)$ we need to show $A\overline{\sim} M=C$

Let $q\in A\overline{\sim} M$

here I got stuck, since I have no idea how to show that $q\in C$.

Might this R is not transitive?

Anti-Symmetric:

Let $A,B\in P(N)$ and assume ARB and BRA we need to show A=B.

let $a\in A$

ARB so exists $M\in P(N)$ so $A\overline{\sim} M=B$

and here I got stuck.

Can we say that M is a set with just a zero element? 
we have exists as not as target so we can`t choose it, I think..
Might R is not anti-symmetric?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: <x,y> is an ordered pair

Comment: By the way, unrelated to your question, "<" and ">" are comparison operators. The correct symbols for tuples are "⟨ ... ⟩", which you can either copy-paste as unicode symbols or get via `\langle \rangle` in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got off to a great start with your transitivity proof!

Note that $M=T\overline{\sim} S.$ Having chosen $q\in A\overline{\sim}M,$ we know that $q=a+m$ for some $a\in A$ and some $m\in M.$ Since $M=T\overline{\sim} S,$ then $m=t+s$ for some $t\in T$ and some $s\in S,$ whence $$q=a+(t+s)=(a+t)+s.$$ Since $a\in A$ and $t\in T,$ then $a+t\in A\overline{\sim} T=B,$ so since $s\in S,$ then $q\in B\overline{\sim} S=C.$ Thus, $A\overline{\sim}M\subseteq C.$

On the other hand, suppose that $q\in C=B\overline{\sim} S,$ so that $q=b+s$ for some $b\in B$ and $s\in S.$ Since $B=A\overline{\sim} T,$ then $b=a+t$ for some $a\in A$ and $t\in T,$ so that $$q=(a+t)+s=a+(t+s),$$ and since $M:=T\overline{\sim}S,$ then $q\in A\overline{\sim}M.$ Thus, $C\subseteq A\overline{\sim}M,$ so $C=A\overline{\sim}M,$ and so $ARM,$ as desired.

---

You started the proof of antisymmetry just as I would have, but you didn't follow through. Indeed, $A\overline{\sim}M=B$ for some $M,$ but also $B\overline{\sim}L=A$ for some $L.$ Thus, $a=b+l$ for some $b\in B$ and $l\in L.$ Furthermore, since $b\in B=A\overline{\sim} M,$ then $b=a'+m$ for some $a'\in A$ and $m\in M,$ so that $a=(a'+m)+l=a'+(m+l).$ It follows that $A\subseteq A\overline{\sim}(M\overline{\sim}L).$

On the other hand, take $x$ to be any element of $A\overline{\sim}(M\overline{\sim}L),$ so that $x=a+(m+l)=(a+m)+l$ for some $a\in A,m\in M,l\in L.$ Since $a+m\in A\overline{\sim}M=B,$ then $x\in B\overline{\sim}L=A.$ Thus, $A\overline{\sim}(M\overline{\sim}L)\subseteq A,$ and so $A=A\overline{\sim}(M\overline{\sim}L).$

Now, if $A=\emptyset,$ it's clear that $A\overline{\sim}M=\emptyset$ by the definition of $\overline{\sim},$ so $B=A$ in that case. Suppose that $A$ is not empty, and let $a_0$ be the least element of $A.$ Since $a_0\in A=A\overline{\sim}(M\overline{\sim}L),$ then $a_0=a+(m+l)$ for some $a\in A,m\in M,l\in L.$ Consequently, $a\le a_0,$ so that $a=a_0$ by our choice of $a_0$ as the least element of $A.$ Thus, since $m,l\in\Bbb N,$ we conclude that $m=l=0.$ From this, we know that $0\in M$ and $0\in L.$

Thus, taking any $a\in A,$ we have that $a=a+0\in A\sim M=B,$ so $A\subseteq B.$ Similarly, $B\subseteq A,$ and so $A=B,$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The usual notation for $\overline{\sim}$ is +.
Show + is associative and communitive.

Clearly, A + {0} = A, so ARA.

Assume ARB, BRC.  Thus exists K,L with A + K = B, B + L = C.
As A + (K + L) = (A + K) + L = B + L = C, ARC.

Comment: Eilot In my proof, I can't use assoiative so it should be clear without using shortcuts like this. Can you show how to prove it stright forward?

Comment: @JohnD: If you can't assume it, prove it. It's not a good idea to say "I can't" without trying first.

Comment: @user21820 I have started to prove it as you can see in the original post. you can see my proof. however, I got stuck

Comment: @JohnD: You misread my comment. You said you "can't use assoiative" (spelling error yours). I said "prove it" (so that you can use it).

Comment: @William I think, transitive I have done. Can you give me hint for proving anti-symmetric?